# How to eliminate null and display value instead

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table as below

```
| EMPID    | MESASURE |          | MEASURE_VAL1    |MEASURE_VAL2    |MEASURE_VAL3   |
| -------- | --------------      |----------       |--------------  |--------------
| A        | MEASURE1            | 10              | NULL           | NULL
| A        | MEASURE2            | NULL            | 20             | NULL
| A        | MEASURE3            | NULL            | NULL           | 30
| A        | MEASURE4            | NULL            | NULL           | NULL
```

I want to get the result as

```
| EMPID | MEASURE 1 | MEASURE 2 | MEASURE 3
-------------------------------------------
| A     |  10       | 20        | 30
```

I tried with where not null and get only one value. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Do you want a MEASURE 4 column to suddenly show up if someone later adds a MMEASURE4 value? (And what about MEASURE5, 6 and 7?)

Comment: Yes, when  there is not null value in measure 4,

Comment: Use MAX aggregation for each measure_val along with grouping by empid

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/ might help.

Comment: What happens if more than 1 measure value is not null for a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like

```
SQL> with test (empid, measure, measure_val1, measure_val2, measure_val3) as
  2    (select 'A', 'MEASURE1', 10  , null, null from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 'MEASURE2', null, 20  , null from dual union all
  4     select 'A', 'MEASURE3', null, null, 30   from dual union all
  5     select 'A', 'MEASURE4', null, null, null from dual
  6    )
  7  select empid,
  8    max(case when measure = 'MEASURE1' then nvl(measure_val1, 0) + nvl(measure_val2, 0) + nvl(measure_val3, 0) end) measure_1,
  9    max(case when measure = 'MEASURE2' then nvl(measure_val1, 0) + nvl(measure_val2, 0) + nvl(measure_val3, 0) end) measure_2,
 10    max(case when measure = 'MEASURE3' then nvl(measure_val1, 0) + nvl(measure_val2, 0) + nvl(measure_val3, 0) end) measure_3,
 11    max(case when measure = 'MEASURE4' then nvl(measure_val1, 0) + nvl(measure_val2, 0) + nvl(measure_val3, 0) end) measure_4
 12  from test
 13  group by empid;

EMPID  MEASURE_1  MEASURE_2  MEASURE_3  MEASURE_4
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A             10         20         30          0

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works however, is there alternative way other than max function.

Comment: You're welcome. Alternative? Sure, MIN function. Partially *kidding*, but - you do need an aggregate function if you want to have result in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SUM` (or `MAX`) aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT empid,
       SUM(measure_val1) AS measure1,
       SUM(measure_val2) AS measure2,
       SUM(measure_val3) AS measure3
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY empid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (EMPID, MESASURE, MEASURE_VAL1, MEASURE_VAL2, MEASURE_VAL3) AS
SELECT 'A', 'MEASURE1', 10,   NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'MEASURE2', NULL, 20,   NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'MEASURE3', NULL, NULL, 30   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'MEASURE4', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMPID | MEASURE1 | MEASURE2 | MEASURE3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 10 | 20 | 30 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8bc0f3661d0d78d975b55dfb88117bab)*